# Playing YouTube embedded video offline

Tags: progressive-web-apps, offline

I am trying to develop a Progressive web application. 
Is it possible to make youtube embedded videos work offline ?

Comment: unless you download the video using the API I doubt you can do this. If you watch the way YouTube streams the videos it is a collection of range requests. So you can't really do it without pre-playing or fetching the video some other way to have the full file.